# Add a text into span tag with td after ajax success

Tags: html, ajax, function, onclick

I am want to add a text into span tag within td after ajax success

```js
function Recommended(parameters){
    var split_para = parameters.split(',');
    var batchID = split_para[0];
    var moduleID = split_para[1];
    var studID = split_para[2];
    var sessionID = split_para[3];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        url: "fn_review_submit.php",
        data:{
            batchid1: batchID,
            moduleid1: moduleID,
            STD_ID: studID,
            sessionid1: sessionID
            },
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);

 if(data == 1) {
     alert('Record update successfully');
     $("#submittername").text('Recommend');
 }else{
    //alert(Error);
    $("#submittername").text('-');
 }

    }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><span id="submittername"></span></td>
```

Issue is that when data come is equal to 1 but span tag is not update a span with recommend, I also use this `$("#submittername").html('Recommend');` but still not update a span. Is there any other way to update span tag with add text after ajax success?

Comment: 1 is not the same as "1". what is your console.log(data) on success says ? does `alert('Record update successfully');` trigger ?

Comment: its give me 1 in data.. when I alert on data then its show me 1

Comment: I only want that how to add text in span tag. can you help me for this? and leave that what data value is come

Comment: $("submittername").text("Your text here");

your syntax is ok, the issue is that your code does not enter the if statement 
does this alert shows up ? alert('Record update successfully');  ???

Comment: alert('Record update successfully'); this alert show that after enter a if statement but i also try this $("submittername").text("Your text here"); as I mention in my question. Its still not updated

Comment: go to your page, open console on chrome and type `$("#submittername").text('Recommend');` does it work ? maybe something to do with document.ready I suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while listing data define its primary key to span tag like this

```
<span id="submittername_<?php echo $primaryid; ?>">sometext</span>
```

and also send this primary id with your parameters so that after in jquery

```
function Recommended(parameters){
    var split_para = parameters.split(',');
    var batchID = split_para[0];
    var moduleID = split_para[1];
    var studID = split_para[2];
    var sessionID = split_para[3];
// id given below
var primaryid = split_para[4];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        url: "fn_review_submit.php",
        data:{
            batchid1: batchID,
            moduleid1: moduleID,
            STD_ID: studID,
            sessionid1: sessionID
            },
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);

 if(data == 1) {
     alert('Record update successfully');
     $("#submittername_"+primaryid ).empty();
 $("#submittername_"+primaryid ).append('Recommend');


 }else{
    //alert(Error);
    $("#submittername_"+primaryid ).empty();
 $("#submittername_"+primaryid ).append('-');
 }

    }
});
}
```